# How to inject HttpServletRequest into a non-resource class?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have successfully injected the `HttpServletRequest` using the `@Context` inside my resource class.

Is it possible to inject the `HttpServletRequest` into a non-resource class? I have created a class that performs various network operations which require values stored inside `HttpSession`. For example...

```
public class RequestExecutor {

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;

    public Response performNetworkRequest(Request request) {

        // Do network request - I want to access the session without passing the session object around my code everywhere.
        return response;
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: JAX-RS and HTTP session. Something looks wrong.

Comment: JAX-RS is supposed to be used to create REST applications. That is, applications that do not use HTTP session.

Comment: Anyways, make your non-resource class a CDI bean (annotate it with `@RequestScope`, for example) and use `@Inject` to inject the `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Yeah I can see why that would be confusing, REST is supposed to be stateless. This project is like middleware between two enterprise systems and is unavoidable :-/

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin So if I understand this correctly, I can use the annotation `@RequestScope` at the class level and change `@Context` to `@Inject`?

Comment: Yep. So you'll have a CDI bean instead of a JAX-RS resource. Just ensure you use `@RequestScoped` from the `javax.enterprise.context` package. Besides request, other scopes are available.

Comment: For your example, you can use the parameter `request` to get the HTTP session, see [HttpServletRequest#getSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession()).

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin I need to research more into what im actually dealing with here.. `@RequestScope` is not available in the framework for some reason.. 

dur has an interesting approach... i'm going to look into it. Thank you

Comment: If you are using jersey, it's possible

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `@Context`, see [JSR-311](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec.html) for JAX-RS 1.1 and [JSR-339](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0_rev_A-mrel-spec/index.html) for JAX-RS 2.0:

> JAX-RS provides facilities for obtaining and processing information about the application deployment context and the context of individual requests. Such information is available to `Application` subclasses (see section 2.1), root resource classes (see chapter 3), and providers (see chapter 4).

You can also initialize sub resources:

> The `ResourceContext` interface provides access to instantiation and initialization of resource or subresource
>   classes in the default per-request scope. It can be injected to help with creation and initialization,
>   or just initialization, of instances created by an application.

See also: [ResourceContext#initResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceContext.html#initResource-T-)

But you could use inheritance:

```
public abstract class AbstractResource {

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;

    protected Response performNetworkRequest() {
        // do something with request
    }
}

@Path("myResource")
public class MyResource extends AbstractResource {
    // some methods 
}
```